# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring, mybatis

Hey I'm using Mybatis with Spring Annotations.

and getting this error:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.mypackage.mappers.QuestionsMapper.Question
```

here is the domain class (sans getters and setters):

```
public class Question {


    String optionsAsString;
    String typeAsString;
    Integer fieldId;
    String title;
    String description;

    public Question(){
    }   
}
```

here is my Mapper.Java class

```
@MapperScan
public interface Mapper {

public List<Question> getQuestions(@Param("shifts") List<Integer> shifts, @Param("job_id") Integer job_id);
}
```

lastly here is the Mapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.mypackage.mappers.Mapper">
<resultMap type="com.mypackage.domain.Question" id="Question">
    <id column="field_id" property="fieldId" />
    <result column="data_type" property="typeAsString" />
    <result column="title" property="title" />
    <result column="description" property="description" />
    <result column="options" property="optionsAsString" />
</resultMap>

<select id="com.mypackage.mappers.Mapper.getQuestions" resultMap="Question" timeout="10">
    SELECT
    f.field_id,
    f.data_type,
    f.title,
    f.options,
    f.description 
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT q.*
        FROM
            question_services qs INNER JOIN
            questions q 
            ON qs.field_id=q.field_id AND q.job_id = qs.job_id INNER JOIN
            services s
            ON qs.service_id = s.service_id and qs.job_id = s.job_id
            WHERE s.job_id = #{job_id} AND s.service_id in
            <foreach item="shift" collection="shifts" open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{shift}
            </foreach>
        ) f
</select>
```

I'm inclined to believe there is something wrong with the xml select statement. Probably with how I am using foreach. I have another mapper using a similar format it just does not use for each and it is not having any problems.

Comment: Do you have another mapping with id="Question"?

Comment: No. That's something I even tried changing incase I had another mapping somewhere named Question. I have searched through my mappings and can't find one and changing the name gives me the same error just with a reference to the new name.

Comment: Is `Mapper.Java` and `Mapper.xml` in one same directory?

Comment: This error just means that you have syntax error in your mapping file (very confusing I would say). You may try to simplify it and start with some small and working file and incrementally change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep It looks like there was an error somewhere in my select statement. I ended up just rewriting it a different way.

```
<select id="getQuestions" resultMap="Question">
    SELECT
        q.field_id,
        q.data_type,
        q.title,
        q.description,
        q.options
    FROM
        questions q
    WHERE
        job_id = #{job_id}
    AND
        field_id
    IN
        (SELECT 
            fs.field_id
        FROM
            question_services qs
        INNER JOIN 
            services s 
        ON
            qs.service_id = s.service_id 
        AND
            qs.job_id = s.job_id
        WHERE
            s.job_id=#{job_id}
        AND
            s.service_id
        IN
        <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="shifts" open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{item}
        </foreach>
        );
</select>
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding this answer since in my case the problem was different but the exception was same . The exception said ,

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.mypackage.model.mymapper.BaseResultMap
```

This can also happen if you have the same mapper xml present in multiple locations and that duplicate xml gets picked up and parsed. Its good to check that even if by mistake you have taken a backup of the mapper xmls and that lies in the location or sub folders which the mybatis configurer scans for.

Comment: This worked for me as I had same names of mappers in two different projects and first project was being referenced in second project or included as a classpath so eventually both mappers were being loaded causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use mapper file auto loading feature instead of. (this solution is recommended)

delete the mybatis.mapperLocations property.

```
mybatis:
  typeAliasesPackage: com.fiberhome.payroll.model
  mapperLocations: classpath*:**/mapper/*.xml
```

change storing directory and file name of mapper file as follow:

And you can use the `@Mapper` instead of the `@MapperScan`.

Add the `@org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper` interface on mapper interfaces as follow:

```
@Mapper
public interface DmClassInfoDao {
    // ...
}
Delete the @MapperScan from java config

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.fiberhome.payroll"})
@MapperScan("com.fiberhome.payroll.dao")
public class MybatisSpringBootApp {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error when extending a resultMap before declaring it in the xml.  Solved by moving the extending `<resultMap>` declaration below the source map, like so:

```
<resultMap id="sourceMap">
  // results
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="extendingMap" extends="sourceMap">
  // more results
</resultMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I had same issue with different solution so hopefully this will help others who find this error.

I was trying to get away from mappers defined in xml and use in java annotations.

Two things caused this error for me

1. I was setting setConfigLocation for mybatis-config.xml plus the setMapperLocations. setMapperLocations scans the package for mappers and the config file had mappers defined so I had duplicates thus "Mapped Statements collection already contains value..."

   ```
    @Bean
    public static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
                    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
                    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
                    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(
                            new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResource("classpath:mybatis-config.xml")
                    );
                    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setTypeAliasesPackage("org.xxxxx");
                  sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(
                            new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:sql/*.xml")
                    );

                    return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
   ```

   2. I had 2 selects of the same name in .xml mapper